# Change color for selected rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Could you tell me please where can I find property source (like in params for event onRowClicked) ,
if I call property onRowSelected. I need to change the color of the rows which I click by checkbox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BvC6.png)

```
grid = {
        columnDefs: [],
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        rowData: null,
        rowGroupPanelShow: 'always',
        getRowStyle: function (params) {                
            //some code for changing background-color
        },
        onSelectionChanged: rowSelectionChanged,
        onRowDoubleClicked: onRowDoubleClicked,
        groupSelectsChildren: false,
        onRowClicked: clickFunction,
        suppressRowClickSelection: true,
        onRowSelected: selectionChangedFunc,
        onGridReady: function() {
            this.api.hideOverlay();
        }
    };
    function selectionChangedFunc(params){
            console.log(params)    
    }

    function clickFunction(params){
            console.log(params)   
    }
```

Comment: post some of your relevant template and component code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/697213/timothy I edited my post

Answer (score 2):

Just use the index of the highlighted item

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows;let i=idx" 
    (click)="selectedRow = i"
    [class.highlighted]="i == selectedRow">{{row.data}}<div>
```

Comment: sorry, but this option does not suit me

Comment: @K_kuz_ sorry, no idea what I should do with your comment.